# Derive Confidence Intervals for Eigenvalues of a Covariance Matrix

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, pca, multivariate-analysis, eigenvalues

I am working with a dataset of n = 273 observations, p = 9 variables for which I have generated principal components. The task I am faced with is:

### Assume the eigenvalues of a covariance matrix ${cov(X)}$ follow a normal distribution, i.e. $\hat{\lambda_i} \sim \bigg(\lambda_i, \frac{2\lambda_i^2}{n}\bigg)$

### Derive simultaneous confidence intervals for the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ using a global confidence level of 95%. Interpret the results.

I'm a little confused as to how to proceed, as the derivation of simultaneous confidence intervals requires terms from the sample covariance matrix $S$, which I cannot generate given only one vector of eigenvalues.

I need to derive the expression for the confidence intervals in such a way that I can then actually produce them using my data in R. How would I derive these intervals?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read its tag wiki.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation for the assumption that the eigenvalues are independent and normally distributed with variance $2\lambda_i^2/n$? As eigenvalues are computed by a complicated numerical algorithm, I would have thought that the only possible approach for confidence intervals in this case are resampling methods like *jackknife* or *bootstrap*.

Comment: Since you're assuming the eigenvalues of $\Sigma = \operatorname{Cov}(X)$ are random, you appear to be working with a hierarchical model in which $\Sigma$ is random and, conditional on it, the data $X$ are obtained randomly.  Solving your problem therefore requires us to know your assumptions about the conditional distribution of $X:$ what is it?

Comment: Given the assumption you have $P\big(\frac{(\hat\lambda_i-\lambda_i)^2}{2\lambda_i^2/n} <z_{\alpha/2}^2\big)=1-\alpha$.  Solving the quadratic inequality gives you an asymmetric confidence interval for $\lambda_i$.

Comment: @Jarle How do you account for the fact the eigenvalues must be ordered?  That is, the very meaning of the $i^\text{th}$ eigenvalue is predicated on some rule for linearly ordering all $n$ eigenvalues.  Thus, any reasonable set of simultaneous confidence intervals must respect that ordering, too.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I fully agree.  It's hard to see how the assumption in the question can be true.  Perhaps it is an asymptotic result?

Comment: @Jarle Perhaps--but that result would depend on particular assumptions, such as that $\Sigma$ has distinct eigenvalues.  Since that's rarely the case (in "spherical" models, for instance, all its eigenvalues are the same), we are left to speculate about what the question assumes and what it is trying to ask.

Comment: @JarleTufto Yes, I apologize for leaving that out - this is an asymptotic result.